# filepicker save image back to the s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, filepicker.io

I have used the [image editor demo](https://www.filepicker.io/demos/) in my site which works great.

The issues I am having is when it comes to saving back.  I want to save it back to filepicker without any user input (not use `filepicker.saveas` function) but it does not work.  I tried the curl call as specified in the docs

```
curl -X POST -d @filename.txt --header "Content-Type:text/plain" https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/gNw4qZUbRaKIhpy-f-b9
```

but just get a generic error from the system.

Comment: Are you looking to save back to the original file (i.e. uploaded from dropbox, save back to dropbox) or the version in your s3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

got it working I left the url= into the source image